# Problem installing TensorFlow through pip

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow2.0

I used the command `pip install tensorflow` and it always ends with this error message:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 
[Errno2] No such file or directory:

'C:\\Users\\xgxbr\\AppData\\Local\\Packages\\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\\LocalCache\\local-packages\\Python38\\site-packages\\tensorboard_plugin_wit\\_vendor\\tensorflow_serving\\sources\\storage_path\\__pycache__\\file_system_storage_path_source_pb2.cpython-38.pyc'
```

How can I properly fix that? is something missing?

I've downloaded the CUDA version for my machine,

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```